# How to read the content of multiple json with Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` for read the content of a json file that have this structure:

```
{"Timestamp":"2018-01-26T21:11:07.2629540+01:00","Level":"Error","MessageTemplate":"Foo"}
{"Timestamp":"2018-01-26T21:21:18.8747758+01:00","Level":"Error","MessageTemplate":"Foo1"}
```

as you can see there are two json object in my `example.json` file. I'm trying to read this in the following way:

first I've created the class model:

```
 public class RootObject
 {
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string MessageTemplate { get; set; }
 }
```

then I save the content of the file in a string: `string content = File.ReadAllText(@"example.json");`

now I get an error on the next line:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

in particular:

> 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 2, position 0.'

how can I handle this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Do you have control over this file? if no, then is each json object placed on separate line in file?

Comment: @niksofteng I doesn't have any control on this file, and yes, each json is on a separate line as in the question

Comment: Read each line (ReadLines) then inside the loop deserialize the line in a single RootObject, finally add each deserialized object to a list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read each line separately, because otherwise the whole file is not a valid JSON object.

```
using System.IO;

List<RootObject> objects = File.ReadAllLines("example.json")
    .Select(line => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(line))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is possible if you use a `JsonSerializer` and a `JsonTextReader` instead of `JsonConvert`.
The trick is to enable `JsonTextReader.SupportMultipleContent`.

```cs
var objects = new List<RootObject>();

var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

using (var stringReader = new StringReader(content))
using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
{
    jsonReader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

    while (jsonReader.Read())
    {
        var json = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);

        objects.Add(json);
    }
}
```

This is more robust than `File.ReadAllLines` because `JsonTextReader` doesn't care about whitespace or line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Because the JSON you're reading is not a valid JSON object.  You can make it an array:

```
[{"Timestamp":"2018-01-26T21:11:07.2629540+01:00","Level":"Error","MessageTemplate":"Foo"},
{"Timestamp":"2018-01-26T21:21:18.8747758+01:00","Level":"Error","MessageTemplate":"Foo1"}]
```

Then you can deserialize it as a collection of that object:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RootObject>>(content);
```

Otherwise you'd have to parse your JSON string to separate it into individual objects and deserialize them one at a time.